# GC overhead limit exceeded when adding properties

Tags: stanford-nlp

I just started using the StanfordCoreNlp library for java and I keep on getting the GC overhead limit error when adding the coref or dcoref annotation properties. Any idea how to solve this?

I changed the JVM maxHeap memory up to 8GB of ram gradually for test purposes and this is definately not the issue.I tried removing several tags from the properties and this is the only one that seem to solve the overhead error, also it only gives the error on StanfordCoreNlp, the simpleCore api works without issue, but is not as effective. The snippet of code is the same as in the provided example on the official documentation from Stanford.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            // run all Annotators on this text
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma,ner, parse, coref");
            StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

// read some text in the text variable
            String text = "who is here?"; // Add your text here!
            Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

// run all Annotators on this text
            pipeline.annotate(document);
```

This is the exact error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils.splitOnChar(StringUtils.java:537)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.Dictionaries.loadGenderNumber(Dictionaries.java:406)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.Dictionaries.<init>(Dictionaries.java:676)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.Dictionaries.<init>(Dictionaries.java:576)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.coref.CorefSystem.<init>(CorefSystem.java:32)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.CorefAnnotator.<init>(CorefAnnotator.java:67)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.coref(AnnotatorImplementations.java:196)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$14(StanfordCoreNLP.java:532)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$$Lambda$25/2137589296.apply(Unknown Source)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$30(StanfordCoreNLP.java:602)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$$Lambda$38/1798286609.get(Unknown Source)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:126)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:149)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:251)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:192)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:188)
    at StanfordCoreNLPtest.main(StanfordCoreNLPtest.java:31)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, this can only be caused by Java running out of memory — here it is just loading dictionaries, it isn’t in any infinite loop. Are you sure that you are specifying how to set the memory available correctly? E.g., if running under Eclipse, you need to be setting the application’s memory not the memory given to eclipse. 8GB should be sufficient to run CoreNLP with any options (unless a document is huge, but document loading happens after loading coref). But you could try with 12GB just in case to see what happens....

Comment: I am using InteliJ and I setted the Jvm machine max memory for the project, I will just use it without the coref and it should be fine